# prevenir clic derecho sobre ciertos elementos jquery-contextmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy creando un contenedor contextmenu con el plugin **jQuery-contextMenu** para añadir contenido (ficheros, carpetas). El contenido se renderiza encima del contenedor.

Estoy intentando prevenir el clic derecho encima de los contenedores `.folder-box` pero no consigo hacerlo. He intentado prevenirlo mediante:

```
$(document).on("contextmenu", ".folder-box", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.context-block').contextMenu(false);
});

$(document).on("contextmenu", ".context-block", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.context-block').contextMenu(true);
});
```

Pero funciona.

```js
const array = [
  {
    idPadre: 40,
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idCarpeta: 41,
    nombre: "Cr2",
    Miembros: ""
  },
  {
    idCarpeta: 44,
    nombre: "Carpeta sin titulo",
    Miembros: "",
    idPadre: 40,
    icono: "fa-folder"
  },
  {
    Miembros: "",
    nombre: "Carpeta sin titulo2",
    idCarpeta: 45,
    idPadre: 40,
    icono: "fa-folder"
  },
  {
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idPadre: 40,
    nombre: "Carpeta sin titulo2aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    idCarpeta: 46,
    Miembros: ""
  },
  {
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idPadre: 40,
    nombre: "Carpeta sin titulo3232",
    idCarpeta: 47,
    Miembros: ""
  },
  {
    nombre: "Carpeta sin titulo211111",
    idCarpeta: 49,
    Miembros: "",
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idPadre: 40
  },
  {
    Miembros: "",
    nombre: "Carpeta sin titulo212312",
    idCarpeta: 50,
    idPadre: 40,
    icono: "fa-folder"
  },
  {
    nombre: "Carpeta sin titulo2222",
    idCarpeta: 51,
    Miembros: "",
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idPadre: 40
  },
  {
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idPadre: 40,
    Miembros: "",
    nombre: "Crarsa",
    idCarpeta: 52
  },
  {
    Miembros: "",
    nombre: "Otra",
    idCarpeta: 53,
    idPadre: 40,
    icono: "fa-folder"
  },
  {
    idPadre: 40,
    icono: "fa-folder",
    nombre: "OMG",
    idCarpeta: 54,
    Miembros: ""
  },
  {
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idPadre: 40,
    Miembros: "",
    nombre: "Carpeta sin titulo",
    idCarpeta: 56
  },
  {
    Miembros: "",
    idCarpeta: 57,
    nombre: "ASD",
    idPadre: 40,
    icono: "fa-folder"
  },
  {
    idPadre: 40,
    icono: "fa-folder",
    Miembros: "",
    idCarpeta: 61,
    nombre: "Carpeta sin titulo2"
  },
  {
    idPadre: 40,
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idCarpeta: 62,
    nombre: "Carpeta sin titulo2",
    Miembros: ""
  },
  {
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idPadre: 40,
    Miembros: "",
    idCarpeta: 69,
    nombre: "Alex"
  },
  {
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idPadre: 40,
    idCarpeta: 70,
    nombre: '"Carpeta sin titulo2"',
    Miembros: ""
  },
  {
    idPadre: 40,
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idCarpeta: 71,
    nombre: "'Carpeta sin titulo2'",
    Miembros: ""
  },
  {
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idPadre: 40,
    Miembros: "",
    idCarpeta: 72,
    nombre: "`Carpeta sin titulo`"
  },
  {
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idPadre: 40,
    idCarpeta: 73,
    nombre: "ASD",
    Miembros: ""
  }
];

const items_menu_default = {
  "new-folder": {
    name: "Nueva carpeta",
    icon: "fas fa-folder-plus",
    callback: function (itemKey, opt, e) {
      if (e.which == 3 || e.which == 2) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  },
  hr: "---------",
  "upload-files": {
    name: "Subir archivos",
    icon: "fas fa-file-upload",
    items: {
      "from-pc": {
        name: "Desde el equipo",
        icon: "fas fa-desktop",
        callback: function (itemKey, opt, e) {
          if (e.which == 3 || e.which == 2) {
            return false;
          }
        }
      },
      "from-url": {
        name: "Desde un enlace",
        icon: "fas fa-link",
        callback: function (itemKey, opt, e) {
          if (e.which == 3 || e.which == 2) {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "upload-folders": {
    name: "Subir carpetas",
    icon: "fas fa-folder-plus",
    callback: function (itemKey, opt, e) {
      if (e.which == 3 || e.which == 2) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
};
const items_folder_default = {
  "change-name": {
    name: "Cambiar nombre",
    icon: "far fa-edit",
    callback: function (item, opt, e) {
      if (e.which == 3 || e.which == 2) {
        return false;
      }

      let id = $(opt.$trigger).attr("class").split(" ")[1];
      change_folder_name(id);
    }
  },
  "share-with": {
    name: "Compartir",
    icon: "far fa-share-square",
    callback: function (item, opt, e) {
      if (e.which == 3 || e.which == 2) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  },
  "move-to": {
    name: "Mover a",
    icon: "fas fa-exchange-alt",
    callback: function (itemKey, opt, e) {
      if (e.which == 3 || e.which == 2) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  },
  hr: "---------",
  remove: {
    name: "Quitar",
    icon: "far fa-trash-alt",
    callback: function (itemKey, opt, e) {
      if (e.which == 3 || e.which == 2) {
        return false;
      }
      let id = $(opt.$trigger).attr("class").split(" ")[1];
      remove_folder(id);
    }
  }
};

$(document).ready(function (e) {
  //Default right click menu
  $.contextMenu({
    selector: ".context-block",
    className: "sm-context-menu",
    items: items_menu_default
  });
  //Button menu
  $.contextMenu({
    selector: ".btn-block",
    className: "sm-context-menu",
    trigger: "none",
    items: items_menu_default
  });
  //Folder option menu
  $.contextMenu({
    selector: '.folder-div-option',
    className: 'sm-context-menu',
    trigger: 'left',
    items: items_folder_default
  });

  array.forEach(function (obj) {
    let id = obj.idCarpeta;
    let name = obj.nombre;
    let icon = obj.icono;
    let short_name = name_length(name);

    $(".lista-carpetas").append(`<div class="folder-box div-item-folder${id}">
                                  <div class="folder">
                                    <div class="folder-div" title="${name}">
                                      <div class="folder-icon">
                                        <i class="fa ${icon}"></i>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="folder-name">${short_name}</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="folder-div-option ${id}" title="Option">
                                      <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>`);
  });
});

/*Prevent default right click*/
$(document).on("contextmenu", ".container-fluid", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});

/*Prevent right click jquery-contextmenu on .folder-box*/
$(document).on("contextmenu", ".folder-box", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //$trigger.contextMenu(false);
});

$(document).on("click", "button.btn", function (e) {
  $(".btn-block").contextMenu();
});

function name_length(name){
  if(name.length > 21){
    return name.substring(0,21)+"...";
  }else{
    return name;
  }
}
```

```css
.container-fluid {
  min-height: 400px;
}

.folder-box{
    float:left;
    width:220px;
}

.folder{
  border: 1px solid #e7eaec;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  user-select: none;
}

.folder .folder-div{
    width:182px; 
    display:inline-block; 
    cursor:pointer;
  }
  .folder-div:hover,
  .folder-div-option:hover{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }
  .folder .folder-div .folder-icon{
    display:inline;
  }
  .folder .folder-div .folder-icon i{
    font-size:15px;
    color:#3d4d5d;
    padding:12px 10px;
  }
  .folder .folder-div .folder-name{
    display:inline; 
  }
  .folder .folder-div-option i{
    font-size:15px;
  }
  .folder .folder-div-option{
    display:inline;
    float:right;
    padding:8px 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:25.65px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.contextMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.contextMenu.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>




<div class="row container-fluid">
  <div class="col-3">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Nuevo</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-9 context-block">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 lista-carpetas"></div>
      <div class="col-12 lista-ficheros"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sólo tienes que cambiar en tu evento, el método *preventDefault* por un *return false*:

```
$(document).on("contextmenu", ".folder-box", function(e){
  return false;
});
```

```js
const array = [
  {
    idPadre: 40,
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idCarpeta: 41,
    nombre: "Cr2",
    Miembros: ""
  },
  {
    idCarpeta: 44,
    nombre: "Carpeta sin titulo",
    Miembros: "",
    idPadre: 40,
    icono: "fa-folder"
  },
  {
    Miembros: "",
    nombre: "Carpeta sin titulo2",
    idCarpeta: 45,
    idPadre: 40,
    icono: "fa-folder"
  },
  {
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idPadre: 40,
    nombre: "Carpeta sin titulo2aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    idCarpeta: 46,
    Miembros: ""
  },
  {
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idPadre: 40,
    nombre: "Carpeta sin titulo3232",
    idCarpeta: 47,
    Miembros: ""
  },
  {
    nombre: "Carpeta sin titulo211111",
    idCarpeta: 49,
    Miembros: "",
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idPadre: 40
  },
  {
    Miembros: "",
    nombre: "Carpeta sin titulo212312",
    idCarpeta: 50,
    idPadre: 40,
    icono: "fa-folder"
  },
  {
    nombre: "Carpeta sin titulo2222",
    idCarpeta: 51,
    Miembros: "",
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idPadre: 40
  },
  {
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idPadre: 40,
    Miembros: "",
    nombre: "Crarsa",
    idCarpeta: 52
  },
  {
    Miembros: "",
    nombre: "Otra",
    idCarpeta: 53,
    idPadre: 40,
    icono: "fa-folder"
  },
  {
    idPadre: 40,
    icono: "fa-folder",
    nombre: "OMG",
    idCarpeta: 54,
    Miembros: ""
  },
  {
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idPadre: 40,
    Miembros: "",
    nombre: "Carpeta sin titulo",
    idCarpeta: 56
  },
  {
    Miembros: "",
    idCarpeta: 57,
    nombre: "ASD",
    idPadre: 40,
    icono: "fa-folder"
  },
  {
    idPadre: 40,
    icono: "fa-folder",
    Miembros: "",
    idCarpeta: 61,
    nombre: "Carpeta sin titulo2"
  },
  {
    idPadre: 40,
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idCarpeta: 62,
    nombre: "Carpeta sin titulo2",
    Miembros: ""
  },
  {
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idPadre: 40,
    Miembros: "",
    idCarpeta: 69,
    nombre: "Alex"
  },
  {
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idPadre: 40,
    idCarpeta: 70,
    nombre: '"Carpeta sin titulo2"',
    Miembros: ""
  },
  {
    idPadre: 40,
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idCarpeta: 71,
    nombre: "'Carpeta sin titulo2'",
    Miembros: ""
  },
  {
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idPadre: 40,
    Miembros: "",
    idCarpeta: 72,
    nombre: "`Carpeta sin titulo`"
  },
  {
    icono: "fa-folder",
    idPadre: 40,
    idCarpeta: 73,
    nombre: "ASD",
    Miembros: ""
  }
];

const items_menu_default = {
  "new-folder": {
    name: "Nueva carpeta",
    icon: "fas fa-folder-plus",
    callback: function (itemKey, opt, e) {
      if (e.which == 3 || e.which == 2) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  },
  hr: "---------",
  "upload-files": {
    name: "Subir archivos",
    icon: "fas fa-file-upload",
    items: {
      "from-pc": {
        name: "Desde el equipo",
        icon: "fas fa-desktop",
        callback: function (itemKey, opt, e) {
          if (e.which == 3 || e.which == 2) {
            return false;
          }
        }
      },
      "from-url": {
        name: "Desde un enlace",
        icon: "fas fa-link",
        callback: function (itemKey, opt, e) {
          if (e.which == 3 || e.which == 2) {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "upload-folders": {
    name: "Subir carpetas",
    icon: "fas fa-folder-plus",
    callback: function (itemKey, opt, e) {
      if (e.which == 3 || e.which == 2) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
};
const items_folder_default = {
  "change-name": {
    name: "Cambiar nombre",
    icon: "far fa-edit",
    callback: function (item, opt, e) {
      if (e.which == 3 || e.which == 2) {
        return false;
      }

      let id = $(opt.$trigger).attr("class").split(" ")[1];
      change_folder_name(id);
    }
  },
  "share-with": {
    name: "Compartir",
    icon: "far fa-share-square",
    callback: function (item, opt, e) {
      if (e.which == 3 || e.which == 2) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  },
  "move-to": {
    name: "Mover a",
    icon: "fas fa-exchange-alt",
    callback: function (itemKey, opt, e) {
      if (e.which == 3 || e.which == 2) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  },
  hr: "---------",
  remove: {
    name: "Quitar",
    icon: "far fa-trash-alt",
    callback: function (itemKey, opt, e) {
      if (e.which == 3 || e.which == 2) {
        return false;
      }
      let id = $(opt.$trigger).attr("class").split(" ")[1];
      remove_folder(id);
    }
  }
};

$(document).ready(function (e) {
  //Default right click menu
  $.contextMenu({
    selector: ".context-block",
    className: "sm-context-menu",
    items: items_menu_default
  });
  //Button menu
  $.contextMenu({
    selector: ".btn-block",
    className: "sm-context-menu",
    trigger: "none",
    items: items_menu_default
  });
  //Folder option menu
  $.contextMenu({
    selector: '.folder-div-option',
    className: 'sm-context-menu',
    trigger: 'left',
    items: items_folder_default
  });

  array.forEach(function (obj) {
    let id = obj.idCarpeta;
    let name = obj.nombre;
    let icon = obj.icono;
    let short_name = name_length(name);

    $(".lista-carpetas").append(`<div class="folder-box div-item-folder${id}">
                                  <div class="folder">
                                    <div class="folder-div" title="${name}">
                                      <div class="folder-icon">
                                        <i class="fa ${icon}"></i>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="folder-name">${short_name}</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="folder-div-option ${id}" title="Option">
                                      <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>`);
  });
});

/*Prevent default right click*/
$(document).on("contextmenu", ".container-fluid", function (e) {
  return false;
});

/*Prevent right click jquery-contextmenu on .folder-box*/
$(document).on("contextmenu", ".folder-box", function(e){
  return false;
  //$trigger.contextMenu(false);
});

$(document).on("click", "button.btn", function (e) {
  $(".btn-block").contextMenu();
});

function name_length(name){
  if(name.length > 21){
    return name.substring(0,21)+"...";
  }else{
    return name;
  }
}
```

```css
.container-fluid {
  min-height: 400px;
}

.folder-box{
    float:left;
    width:220px;
}

.folder{
  border: 1px solid #e7eaec;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  user-select: none;
}

.folder .folder-div{
    width:182px; 
    display:inline-block; 
    cursor:pointer;
  }
  .folder-div:hover,
  .folder-div-option:hover{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }
  .folder .folder-div .folder-icon{
    display:inline;
  }
  .folder .folder-div .folder-icon i{
    font-size:15px;
    color:#3d4d5d;
    padding:12px 10px;
  }
  .folder .folder-div .folder-name{
    display:inline; 
  }
  .folder .folder-div-option i{
    font-size:15px;
  }
  .folder .folder-div-option{
    display:inline;
    float:right;
    padding:8px 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:25.65px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.contextMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.contextMenu.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>




<div class="row container-fluid">
  <div class="col-3">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Nuevo</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-9 context-block">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 lista-carpetas"></div>
      <div class="col-12 lista-ficheros"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```